# Unable to configure webpack.config file

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Whenever I run `webpack-dev-server` it throws this error:

`....webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\....`

Here's the webpack.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
        "./src"
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: ['react-hot-loader','babel-core?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: is there an `index.*` in your `src` folder? Does the `src` folder exist? Try making the last entry point a file instead of a folder e.g. `./src` to `./src/index.js`

Comment: now it says `cant resolve react-hot`, updated my code!

Comment: did you `npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader`?

Comment: now i did, update code again! errors keep on bundling up! Now throws: `babel-core\index.js in not a loader must have normal or pitch function`

Comment: update your question with the contents of your `package.json`. Did you `npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015`?

Comment: @RicoKahler updated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136063/discussion-between-rico-kahler-and-jaskaran-singh-puri).

Comment: im there! lets talk

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Windows (`'C:\...'` in the error message), and webpack [expects](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#windows-paths) windows path separators, like `\`, not `/`. Could you try `".\src\your_entry_file.js"` instead `"./src"`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

update your package json to this:

```
{
  "name": "react-todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install` from the root of your project folder

Update your `webpack.config.js` to this

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: [
        "webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
        "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
        "./src/app.js" // or whatever your entry file is
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            // the loader should be broken up into two objects
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx?harmony'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'src') }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
};
```

Download [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/master/server.js) `server.js` file and save it to the project folder.

Then try `npm start`

hopefully that works. good luck. Refer [here](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/)

Comment: Error again, check discussion

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri oh and i forgot, do `npm install --save-dev express` too